# using regular expression for preg replace

Tags: php, asp.net, regex, regular-language

i wanna to know the best regular expression to replace this string with the vid_id in it

```
$code = '&lt;object width=&quot;420&quot; height=&quot;345&quot;&gt;<br />
    &lt;param name=&quot;movie&quot; value=&quot;http://www.badoobook.com/clips/swf/player.swf&quot;&gt;&lt;/param&gt;<br />
    &lt;param name=&quot;allowFullScreen&quot; value=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;/param&gt;&lt;param name=&quot;flashvars&quot; value=&quot;vid_id=100226&amp;MainURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bado  obook.com%2Fclips&amp;em=1&quot;&gt;<br />
    &lt;embed src=&quot;http://www.badoobook.com/clips/swf/player.swf&quot; flashvars=&quot;vid_id=100226&amp;MainURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.  badoobook.com%2Fclips&amp;em=1&quot; type=&quot;application/x-shockwave-flash&quot; allowScriptAccess=&quot;always&quot; width=&quot;420&quot; height=&quot;345&quot; allowFullScreen=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;/embed&gt;&lt;/object&gt;'
$regular = '';
$code = preg_replace($regular ,'$1' , $code);
echo $code;
```

the vid id in this code is

> value=`&quot;`vid_id=**100226**`&amp;`

thanks for helping

Comment: the big proplem that i face is the &lt; i think there is some special things in regulat expression to read it , and i don't know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Regex like this:

```
(?<=vid_id=)\d+
```

This uses a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match any number of digits that are preceded by the literal character set "vid_id="

Here it is again with RegexBuddy comments:

```
@"
(?<=          # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   vid_id=       # Match the characters “vid_id=” literally
)
\d            # Match a single digit 0..9
   +             # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"
```

You have tagged your question with both `php` and `asp.net` so i'm not sure which implementation you are after. Here is both:

Asp.Net (C#)

```
Regex.Replace(@"...uot;vid_id=100226&amp;...", @"(?<=vid_id=)\d+", "[Your value here]")
```

php

```
echo preg_replace("(?<=vid_id=)\d+", "[Your value here]", "...uot;vid_id=100226&amp;...");
```

Answer (score 2):

use this regular expression:

```
vid_id=(\d+)
```

Comment: this will give me the id , but the thing i want is to replace the whole code with the nember